# Celery task .get() not working

Tags: django, docker, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I will really appreciate help with this!

This is my first attempt at using Celery with Django in Docker containers and I can't get passed this problem after many hours of reading and experimenting.

**PROBLEM**

I can import the task from `polls.task` and run it using `.delay()` as follows:

```
python manage.py shell
from polls.tasks import add
task = add.delay(4,4)
```

When I run this, I can see a message through the rabbitmq container.

If I execute task.id, i can get the task id.

HOWEVER, if I run `task.get()`, **the program just hangs**. I see no action on any of the containers and I get no result.

I have also noticed that, when I run dc-up and start all the containers, I get the following output on the worker container, which seems correct including being able to see my task registered:

```
worker      |  -------------- default@5d0902ad9e2a v4.1.0 (latentcall)
worker      | ---- **** ----- 
worker      | --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs-x86_64-with-debian-8.10 2018-03-30 09:45:01
worker      | -- * - **** --- 
worker      | - ** ---------- [config]
worker      | - ** ---------- .> app:         composeexample:0x7f2f3255e320
worker      | - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://admin:**@rabbitmq:5672//
worker      | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/0
worker      | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
worker      | -- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
worker      | --- ***** ----- 
worker      |  -------------- [queues]
worker      |                 .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
worker      | 
worker      | [tasks]
worker      |   . polls.tasks.add
worker      | [2018-03-30 10:45:34,722: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://admin:**@rabbitmq:5672//
worker      | [2018-03-30 10:45:34,746: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
worker      | [2018-03-30 10:45:35,799: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
worker      | [2018-03-30 10:45:35,827: INFO/MainProcess] default@a7d75a442646 ready.
```

I suspect that I am missing some form of communication between rabbitmq and the worker. I also wonder if I am simply starting the worker incorrectly, or maybe not at all. I can't really tell.

I have double-checked that my environment variables are setup in both django and worker containers.

**SETUP**

I have the following setup in Docker: Django, Redis(for backend), RabbitMQ(for messages), PSQL, Celery (separate container for worker)

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ADD requirements.txt /code/

WORKDIR /code/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    git

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

# create unprivileged user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  dbtest:
    image: postgres:10.1
    container_name: postgrestest
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresl/data/
    networks:
      - lofi
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.8
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - lofi
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.4
    container_name: rabbitmq
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
      - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin
    networks:
      - lofi
  django:
    container_name: djcelerytest
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - dbtest
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - lofi
  worker:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: worker
    command: sh ./run_celery.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    networks:
      - lofi

networks:
  lofi:

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
```

I have the following settings in the .env file, used to set Django and worker containers:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:mypass@rabbitmq//
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
```

Here is the run_celery.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# wait for RabbitMQ server to start
sleep 10

# run Celery worker for our project myproject with Celery configuration stored in Celeryconf
su -m myuser -c "celery worker -E -A composeexample.celeryconf -Q default -n default@%h  --loglevel=INFO"
```

The task I'm trying to run is in tasks.py:

```
from composeexample.celeryconf import app
from .models import AddStore

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    value = x + y
    new = AddStore(value=value)
    new.save()
    return value
```

Comment: I'm seeing 2 issues. 1) `from .models import AddStore` I would suggest use `from APPNAME.models import AddStore` 2) Import this into `add` function after `def add(x, y):` this line.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't appear to be the problem. even if I comment out the model object reference, .get() does not return any result. it just hangs.

Comment: So you removed `new = AddStore(value=value) and new.save()` the tow lines and import and tried?

Comment: Then try with Shared Task, `@shared_task` write this line instead of `@app.task` AND one more try `@app.task(bind=True)` instead of `@app.task`

Comment: no improvement. >>> from polls.tasks import add
>>> task = add.delay(4,4)
>>> task.id
'73b55e8d-73eb-447c-843f-876577e58270'
>>> task.get()
nada

Comment: You tried in both way by adding True and shared?

Comment: yes, tasks.py looks like this now: from celery import shared_task
from composeexample.celeryconf import app


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    value = x + y
    return value

Comment: i wondered if it is because i use `/code` as the directory for the volume path but if the task is being registered properly then it must be able to be located.

Comment: i figured it out ... i cleaned up the celery worker command to set `--loglevel=DEBUG` and then removed the -Q and -n options it works perfectly!

Comment: You can add answer, so others can find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, in the `run_celery.sh` file, my command to start the celery worker included the `-Q default` option, an option that no longer exists according to the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/genindex.html).

So if you simply change this:

```
su -m myuser -c "celery worker -E -A composeexample.celeryconf -Q default -n default@%h  --loglevel=INFO"
```

to this:

```
su -m myuser -c "celery worker -E -A composeexample.celeryconf -n default@%h  --loglevel=INFO"
```

And I can call `task.get()` with no issue.

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this, this got me un-stuck!